# How does Polearm Master's extra attack work with magical properties?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, weapons

The feat Polearm Master states that:

> When you take the Attack action and attack with only a glaive, halberd, quarterstaff, or spear, you can use a bonus action to make a melee attack with the opposite end of the weapon; this attack uses the same ability modifier as the primary attack. The weapon's damage die for this attack is a d4, and the attack deals bludgeoning damage.

Let's say someone got a magical weapon, like a Stirring Dragon's Wrath Halberd. It has this property:

> Whenever you roll a 20 on your attack roll with this weapon, each creature of your choice within 5 feet of the target takes 5 damage of the type dealt by the dragon's breath weapon.

> You gain a +1 bonus to attack and damage rolls made using the weapon. On a hit, the weapon deals an extra 1d6 damage of the type dealt by the dragon's breath weapon.

Also it has reach, as any halberd.

What property does this extra attack inherit from the weapon? The feat is explicit in that we get to keep the ability modifier but change the damage die to a d4.

What about the reach property: can you do this attack at reach?

What about this +1 to attack and damage rolls and +1d6 dragon damage? What about this effect triggered on rolling a 20?

Answer (score 1):

## The weapon's extra bonuses add to the feat.

The first thing we need to do is remember that [Specific Beats General](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/introduction#SpecificBeatsGeneral):

> If a specific rule contradicts a general rule, the specific rule wins

In this case, the [Polearm Master](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/polearm-master) feat is the general rule as it applies to **all** polearms, and the bonuses of the [Stirring Dragon's Wrath Halberd](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/4047217-dragons-wrath-weapon) is the specific one as they apply only to this specific weapon. There aren't any rule contradictions that we have to worry about here, but it's helpful to keep this in mind as the bonuses from the weapon simply add to those of the feat.

This means that a Stirring weapon would do the AOE damage on *any* Nat20 hit, regardless of whether is was a normal attack or the one gained from the feat. Furthermore, the bonus action attack would gain a +1d6 of the dragon's breath weapon damage type as the weapon *specifically* says "the weapon deals an extra 1d6 damage".

Finally, **all** of these attacks benefit from the weapon's [Reach](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/equipment#WeaponProperties) property as nothing in that property says there are limits to *which* attacks are affected:

> This weapon adds 5 feet to your reach when you attack with it, as well as when determining your reach for opportunity attacks with it.